# Rotate div after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a sort of crash test dummy, when you click in the `document` window my `.person` div will move right and then at the end animate tilt forward, and then tilt back to its original place.

I've got the css for the transform working, only its tilting my `div` immediately and not at the end of the movement? sorry if this is hard to understand, I've created a jsFiddle to explain...

http://jsfiddle.net/4mzg8/3/

```
// On click my .person div will move right, once moved it needs to tilt forward and then backwards - as though its hit a wall...

$(document).on('click',function(){
    $('.person').animate({ "left": "+=250px" }, 500, crashImpact(30));
});

function crashImpact(tilt) {
    $('.person').css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + tilt + 'deg)'
    });
}
```

Comment: crashImpact(30); is immediately invoked. In order to pass it as callback, it's only "crashImpact". You have to provide tilt parameter in some other way.

Comment: Cant help, but you made my day with your little CSS Man! :D haah

Answer (score 1):

It needs a little work, but you can do the whole thing in CSS just by adding a class and chaining animations...

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mzg8/7/) - (Chrome)

JS

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('.person').addClass('go');
});
```

CSS

```
.person.go {
    -webkit-animation-delay:0, .5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.5s, .5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1, 1;
    -webkit-animation-name:animForward, animTilt;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animForward {
    from {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 400px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animTilt {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 brilliant CSS3 solution, nice separation of concerns. If you want to leave the person tilted though in the end you need to leave `45deg` instead of `0deg` at the 100% keyframe: `@-webkit-keyframes animTilt {0% {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);} 100% {-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click',function(){
    $('.person').animate({ "left": "+=250px" },500,function(){
        crashImpact(30);
    });
});

function crashImpact(tilt) {
    $('.person').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + tilt + 'deg)'
    });
}
```

I modified your code. Check here :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/4mzg8/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have written:

```
$('.person').animate({ "left": "+=250px" }, 500, crashImpact(30));
```

This will call `crashImpact function` immediately.

Change it to:

```
$('.person').animate({ "left": "+=250px" },500,function(){
    crashImpact(30);
});
```

This will call `crashImpact function` after execution of `animate` is completed.

`transition` property will rotate `.person` smoothly.

Write:

CSS:

```
.transform{
    transition:all 1s;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}
```

JS:

```
function crashImpact(tilt) {
    $('.person').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + tilt + 'deg)'
    }).addClass("transform");
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mzg8/5/)